# error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for ‘template<class _Tp, class _Dp> class std::unique_ptr’

Tags: c++, c++11, pybind11

Before we start, I am a complete noob in C++11, had used C several years ago.

I am trying to write a python binding of a C++11 code using pybind11 and is getting a **subjected** error. I am basically following this [guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/sdk/tensorrt-developer-guide/index.html#extending) from Nvidia people and is stuck at this error. 
Can any nice soul point me to the right direction?

**Definition**:

```
template<int zoom_factor>
class UpSamplePlugin: public nvinfer1::IPluginExt
{
public:
    UpSamplePlugin() {}

    // Create the plugin at runtime from a byte stream.
    UpSamplePlugin(const void* buffer, size_t size)
    {
        assert(size == sizeof(mInputDims)); // assert datatype of input
        mInputDims = *reinterpret_cast<const nvinfer1::Dims*>(buffer);
    }
...
}
```

**Call**:

```
py::class_<UpSamplePlugin, nvinfer1::IPluginExt, std::unique_ptr<UpSamplePlugin, py::nodelete>>(m, "UpSamplePlugin")
        // Bind the normal constructor as well as the one which deserializes the plugin
        //.def(py::init<const nvinfer1::Weights*, int>())
        .def(py::init<const void*, size_t>())
    ;
```

**Error**:

```
/media/.../plugin/pyUpSample.cpp: In function ‘void pybind11_init_upsampleplugin(pybind11::module&)’:
/media/.../plugin/pyUpSample.cpp:13:90: error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for ‘template<class _Tp, class _Dp> class std::unique_ptr’
     py::class_<UpSamplePlugin, nvinfer1::IPluginExt, std::unique_ptr<UpSamplePlugin, py::nodelete>>(m, "UpSamplePlugin")
                                                                                          ^
/media/.../plugin/pyUpSample.cpp:13:90: note:   expected a type, got ‘UpSamplePlugin’
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no type called `UpSamplePlugin`, this is just a template.
So you must do something like `UpSamplePlugin<T>`.  In your case it should be `UpSamplePlugin<zoom_factor>`

Try the following code, ***if this declaration is inside the template:***

```
py::class_<UpSamplePlugin<zoom_factor>, nvinfer1::IPluginExt, std::unique_ptr<UpSamplePlugin, py::nodelete>>(m, "UpSamplePlugin")
    // Bind the normal constructor as well as the one which deserializes the plugin
    //.def(py::init<const nvinfer1::Weights*, int>())
    .def(py::init<const void*, size_t>())
;
```

The compiler will "create" a new type that corresponds to `UpSamplePlugin<zoom_factor>`.

***If it is not inside the template:***

Create another template (it could be a template function), that can be called with the zoom_factor to be any constant type:

```
template<int zoom_factor>
void doSomething() {
    py::class_<UpSamplePlugin<zoom_factor>, nvinfer1::IPluginExt, std::unique_ptr<UpSamplePlugin, py::nodelete>>(m, "UpSamplePlugin")
    // Bind the normal constructor as well as the one which deserializes the plugin
    //.def(py::init<const nvinfer1::Weights*, int>())
    .def(py::init<const void*, size_t>())
;    
}
```

Then you can call this function with any ***COMPILE TIME KNOWN*** `zoom_factor`