# Using pybind11, is there a way to bind a c++ function that takes a double pointer to custom type (abstract class)

Tags: c++, pybind11

Using pybind11, I am trying to bind double pointer to custom type (abstract class). But I am not seeing any example which explains how to do.

I have class **ITest** which is abstract and has pure virtual function, which takes argument as double pointer to other abstract class **IValue**, as shown in below code snippet.

```
    '''
        class IValue
        {
          virtual long get() = 0;
        }
        
        class ITest
        {
        virtual fnDoublePointerarg(wchar_t* value, IValue** obj) = 0;
        }
    '''
```

How do I create binding for double pointer in pybind for classes? Any examples to achieve it, is appreciated.

More details:

I created a trampoline class as it is abstract class and pybind11 cannot instantiate as below

```
class PyIValue : public IValue
{
  public IValue::IValue;
  long get(){
    PYBIND11_OVERRIDE_PURE(
            long, 
            IValue,     
            get,          
            );
  }

};

class PyITest : public ITest
{
public:
    using ITest::ITest;
    int fnDoublePointerarg(const wchar_t* domainId, IValue** ppOb)  {
        PYBIND11_OVERRIDE_PURE(
            int, 
            ITest,     
            fnDoublePointerarg,          
            std::wstring domainId,
            IValue** ppOb);
   }
};

PYBIND11_MODULE(Example, m) {
    m.doc() = "pybind11 example plugin"; // Optional module docstring
    
    py::class_<ITest, PyITest>(m, "ITest")
        .def(py::init<>())
        .def("fnDoublePointerarg",ITest::fnDoublePointerarg)
```

}

Comment: It isn't clear what you mean by "binding" `obj` just needs to be a pointer to a pointer to `IValue` Often, this happens when you have an array of pointers to `IValue` in which case a pointer to that array is what `obj` should be. It may be that the purpose is to alter the pointer to `IValue` perhaps to somehow attach it in Python.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I added more details to the query. I mean PYBIND11_MODULE .def for the function. As it is not compiling.

Comment: Take a look here - it might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66227840/how-to-wrap-class-template-consisting-virtual-function-with-pybind